# How do I convert the row ID on a database table into an enum?

Tags: c#

I am going to have a table with a structure like:

- Column 1: int ID
- Column 2: string UserMessage

People will be adding rows to the database and the code I am running will not know how many rows there are.

I would like to be able to convert the int ID field into an enum so when people are coding they are able to use that to reference the UserMessages rather than a random int.

Is there a graceful way of doing this in C#?

Comment: What do you mean by random int? Id would be unique isn't it? Id is id of message? Where do you have id of user? User and UserMessage are two another objects/entities/tables so mayby you should have two tables: Users(Id, Name, Email) and UserMessages(Id, UserId (foreign key to User.Id), Message).
Also please be more specific about question what and especially why you want to do.

Comment: Yes the int will be the row ID but if there are dozens of messages I anticipate expecting everyone to remember magic numbers going wrong at some point so I would like to convert these ints to enums.  The ID of the user is not relevant at the moment, they will be another int column linked to a different database

Comment: I am not sure where I am not being specific with my question?  I need a way to convert the ints in the ID column to enums to make coding easier for everyone.  What additional information would help?

Comment: You cannot have enum with no values specified before. You would have thousands of IDs. How you want to accoplish enumdefinition: enum is a value type defined by a set of named constants. How you want to specify those constants in code? It is not possible.

Comment: @Stefan Please [edit] your question to include a description what this specific table is used for and how the number of rows inside this table is changing. Then explain where you want to use your enum and how it should be used. Depending on what you want to do you might not need this table at all.

Comment: @Progman, would that information help?  I do not want to add too much clutter to the question.  The more specific I make it the less helpful it will be to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would want to create a resource table like this, which maps ints (or enums) to messages (eventually in different languages).

To do this, you can use T4 templates. These are C#-like scripts, that execute *at build time* and can generate i.e. an enum from a database. You'd probably better use another string instead of an id field, though (because that's easier to remember).

**Update** (Sorry for the late reply)

Here's a chunk of t4 code that converts a list of names from a resource dictionary to an enum (in this case, the names are picked from a .resx file, you would want the first part to be changed to access your database). Do note that the database query will run *at compile time*.

Name this something like Resources.tt. And add a reference to Microsoft.TextTransform NuGet (read the docs on correct consumption of that package - I'm using an older version, so this might have changed).

```
// <autogenerated />
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml"#>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO"#>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#
            List<Tuple<String, String>> values = new List<Tuple<String, String>>();
            // Read in resx file
            string fileName = this.Host.ResolvePath("Resources.resx");
            using (Stream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
                {
                    string key = string.Empty;
                    while (xmlReader.Read())
                    {
                        if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xmlReader.Name == "data")
                        {
                            if (xmlReader.HasAttributes)
                            {
                                while(xmlReader.MoveToNextAttribute())
                                {
                                    if (xmlReader.Name == "name")
                                    {
                                        key = xmlReader.Value;
                                    }
                                }

                            }

                        }
                        // The "value" is normally a sub-element of "data", only then we generate code here
                        // (the iteration goes over _all_ nodes in sequence, regardless of their depth)
                        if (xmlReader.Name=="value")
                        {
                            if (key != string.Empty)
                            {
                                var text = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                
                                values.Add(Tuple.Create(key, text));
                                key = string.Empty;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
#>using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;

namespace ApplicationResources
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This enum is automatically generated from the content of
    /// <#= fileName #>
    /// </summary>
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1027:MarkEnumsWithFlags", Justification = "A String id is never a flag")]
    [GeneratedCode("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating", "10.0.0.0")]
    public enum StringResourceId
    {
        None = 0,
<#
        int unnumberedId = 100000; // To make sure the textual named entries also get unique values
        foreach (Tuple<String, String> enumValue in values)
        {
            // detect whether enumValue is a number
            int number;
            if (int.TryParse(enumValue.Item1, out number))
            {
                string enumString = "Id_" + enumValue.Item1;
#>

        /// <summary>
        /// <#= enumValue.Item2 #>
        /// </summary>
        <#= enumString #> = <#= number #>,
<#
            }
            else
            {
#>

        /// <summary>
        /// <#= enumValue.Item2 #>
        /// </summary>
        <#= enumValue.Item1 #> = <#= unnumberedId++ #>,
<#
            }
        }
#>

    }
}
```

Comment: So if I have an id column and I put the string "ID_BAD_SERVER" it will convert that to an enum value ID_BAD_SERVER?

Comment: To reach that you have to specify conversion in your EF core DbContext class in method OnModelCreating: 
modelBuilder
        .Entity<MyEntity>()
        .Property(e => e.MyEnumProperty)
        .HasConversion(
            v => v.ToString(),
            v => (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), v));

Comment: @zolty13, do you have an example to hand?  The walkthroughs do not seem to line up with what I am seeing?

Comment: I do not see what you want to reach. You will have many ids in DB and want to have enum which map all of them?